# Count distinct based on one column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've the following table

```
ID | AreaPath | IterationPath |

1       Area1     Iteration1
2       Area2     Iteration1
2       Area2     Iteration2
```

I want to use count only on the ID column.

The wanted output should be:

```
CountID | ID | AreaPath | IterationPath |

    1      1    Area1      Iteration1
    2      2    Area2      Iteration1
    2      2    Area2      Iteration2
```

The following query :

```
select 
    count(TRV.ID ) as CountID, 
    TRV.ID,
    TRV.AreaPath, 
    TRV.IterationPath 
FROM table TRV 
Group BY AreaPath, IterationPath
```

Gives me the following output:

```
CountID | ID | AreaPath | IterationPath |

    1      1    Area1      Iteration1
    1      2    Area2      Iteration1
    1      2    Area2      Iteration2
```

How should I change it to get the wanted output?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? BTW, this is what I call the correct way to ask questions. All do like @OrenAshkenazy does!

Comment: Since you're grouping by both `AreaPath` and `IterationPath`, only unique combinations will be counted, so your query result is correct.  Why are you expecting CountID to be output as 2?  You'd need to only group by AreaPath.

Comment: @Quassnoi: Except their query couldn't possibly have compiled in SQL Server...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In all big four databases except MySQL:

```
SELECT  COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY id) cnt,
        m.*
FROM    mytable m
```

In MySQL:

```
SELECT  (
        SELECT  COUNT(*)
        FROM    mytable mi
        WHERE   mi.id = m.id
        ) cnt,
        m.*
FROM    mytable m
```

Comment: Which are the big four databases? I can only recall Oracle, MSSQL and DB2 (if I'm not wrong :] ).

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, PostgreSQL.

Comment: They want `COUNT(DISTINCT)`, though, and SQL Server doesn't do `COUNT(DISTINCT) OVER ...`.